# Rest Security Ensure Resource Delete

Tags: rest, security, denial-of-service

**Background:**
I'm a new developer fresh out of college at a company that uses RPC architectural style for a lot its internal services.
They also seem to change which tool they use behind the scenes pretty frequently, so the tight coupling between the client and server implementations in RPC is problematic. 
 I was tasked with rewriting one of the services, and I feel a RESTful api would be a good match because the backing technology can only deal with files anyway, but I have a few questions.
My understanding of REST so far is that you break operations up as much as possible and shift the focus to resources, so both the client and the server together make a state machine with the server mainly handling the transitions through hypermedia.
**Example:**
say you have a service that takes a file and splits it in two byte-wise.
I would design the sequence for this like

1. the client would POST the file they want split,

   - server splits the file
   - server writes both result pieces to a temp folder
   - server returns that the client should GET and both files URI's
2. the client sends a GET for the piece

   - server returns the piece and that the client should DELETE the URI

   the client sends a DELETE for the URI

and 2 and 3 are done for both pieces.
**My question is:**
 How do you ensure that the pieces get deleted at the end?

- a client could just not follow step 3
- if you combine step 2&3, a malicious (or negligent) client could just stop after step 1
- but if you combine them all, isn't that just RPC over HTTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the 2 pieces in question are inseparable, then they are in fact just properties of a single resource.

And yes, if a POST/PUT must be followed by a DELETE, then you're probably just trying to shoehorn RPC into a REST-style architecture.

There's no real definition of what "REST" actually is, but if the one thing certain about it is that it MUST be stateless; i.e. every separate request must be self-sufficient - it cannot depend on a previous request, and cannot mandate subsequent requests.